# Plotting thousands of data sets in one matplotlib plot

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib

I am plotting about ten thousand line plots within one matplotlib figure (I know, this is not visually appealing, but necessary in this case). Each line consist of about 100 data points and is plottet by `plt.plot(x, y[i], ls='-')`, where `i` iterates over all 10,000 data sets within `y`, and `x` always stays the same.
Right now, I am doing this iterating over `i` in a for loop after `plt.figure()`, which takes huge amounts of time. I have to save the plot as PNG to disk. Is there any way to do it faster?

Comment: unless you absolutely have to use matplotlib, pyqtgraph is much quicker.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention that I have to export that graphic as a hq png file. It seems that pyqtgraph is for screen plotting.

Comment: http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/exporting.html